# Windows Security Center service can't be started

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, services

I'm using Win 7 64.

I tried to activate it from "services" but it doesn't work. Also, I scanned my pc with ESET Smart 4 & Super Anti-spyware but nothing was found.

Does anyone know a way to get this to work, besides reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Can you do it in safe mode?

Comment: Try `sfc /scannow`

Comment: See this...http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/the-windows-security-center-service-cant-be/d8250e7a-ee3c-4302-8ca6-9e2a10262feb

Comment: And this...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519899

Comment: Just to mention; I would advice not to use ESET Smart Security along with Super Anti-spyware as far as they can interfere with each other and you can end up in a dead-race, resulting in unusable system.

Comment: @laika perhaps that is not specific to those two but just running two anti malware generally. if so then you should say that rather than making it sound like a specific issue with them

Answer (score 1):

Might sound silly, but you didn't mention if it's persistent... does it continue after restarting the machine?

Have a read through this [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519899), I'll include the jist of it here.

> 1. Click **Start**, and then type **services.msc** in the **Search** box
> 2. Under **Programs**, click **Services**.
> 3. On the right side of the window, locate the **Security Center** service in the list of services.
> 4. Right-click **Security Center**, and then select **Properties**.
> 5. From the **Startup type** drop-down list, select **Automatic (delayed start)**.
> 6. Under **Service Status**, click **Start**.
> 7. Click **Apply**, click **OK**, and then close the Services window.

If you get any error messages, post them up here as they will be key to what the problem is (there is one example of an error message and the fix for it on the linked KB.)

Comment: thanks for answering.
but i do "sfc/scannow" but nothing founds.

no error code !

as i said i try "services.msc" but it disables again weather i restart the pc or not.

Comment: thanks for answering.but i do "sfc/scannow" but nothing founds.
no error code !
 @Moab: i've already check those links. also many win 7 forum on the web & Microsoft supporting page! but doesn't work.
 as i said i try "services.msc" but it disables again weather i restart the pc or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems symptomatic of a rootkit infection, which are difficult for AV programs to spot.

Try running combofix from http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix and see if it finds anything.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and finally solved it. I installed AVG internet security and ran a full scan. It detected 3 viruses. After removing that threats Security center service started without stopping.