# In Windows 10, I can't start the Windows Security Center Service

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10, in "Security and Maintenance", If I click "turn on now" for "Windows Security Center Service" it says "The Windows Security Center Service can't be started".

[image]

Ramhound suggested this question [Windows Security Center service can't be started](https://superuser.com/questions/318265/windows-security-center-service-cant-be-started)    It is actually windows 7 and i'm on windows 10, though I can apply an answer there, here. When I do I get an error.

Going to services.msc , Security Center, properties, Automatic (delayed start)

Then clicking Start.

I get this error "Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start"

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72208/discussion-between-ramhound-and-barlop).

Answer (score 4):

> In Windows 10, in "Security and Maintenance", If I click "turn on now"
>   for "Windows Security Center Service" it says "The Windows Security
>   Center Service can't be started".

You need to verify that the following services are configured to Automatic (delayed start) and are running.

- Security Center
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
- Windows Management Instrumentation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that msconfig is on normal bootup and not selective bootup.   I changed msconfig to normal boot and then it was fine.

There is one other solution which I had tried before that, to get the security center started, which is a temporary workaround and doesn't fix the underlying problem which had disabled other services e.g. the firewall, not  just security center. The approach was to see in services.msc,  to check that the security center service was set to automatic(delayed), and since that gave an error 1068 about dependent services, to check properties..dependencies, and that dependent services are also set likewise, so to check that e.g. "Remote Procedure Call (RPC)" and "Windows Management Instrumentation" were set to automatic(delayed), and were started.

But for my case, setting msconfig to normal, rather than "selective startup", was the (best) solution.

Comment: @Ramhound I think the solution you mention is potentially useful to people(even though in my particular case it didn't fix the deeper problem, it did get security center started which I asked about). And i'd like to mention it. I can do it without mentioning you or your answer, if you prefer. Is that ok with you?

Comment: Barlop, that is certainly a good find!  But if you don't mind me asking, wouldn't the discovery of the *msconfig selective boot* configuration have been much more appropriate as additional (and crucial) information within the original question, rather than an answer?

Comment: @Run5k I agree. I put it there originally, see the edits to ramhound's answer! He rejected the edit. He also edited my answer rewriting it so I edited it again. Look at the revisions for a laugh! And there is some discussion in chat between me and him at the link, and in the main chat between me him and bob,and between me and journeymangeek (like me and you, journeyman geek liked the idea of a note. but I think bob like ramhound, wasn't so in favour of a note).I had originally added the additional info to his answer and accepted it! But we settled on me posting my own answer and accepted that.

Comment: @Run5k he did want to delete his answer but he had an issue doing so! (something related to upvotes!)

Comment: @barlop - Run5k's suggestion was for you to include the information in your question, not as an edit to my answer, there is a reason for that.

Comment: @Run5k Your suggestion is like putting the answer into the question. Had I known it was on selective startup I would not have asked the question in the first place. The site is superuser. Your/Run5k's suggestion is like saying "there is a powercut why is the light off" Or, "the light switch is in the off position but what can  I do to turn the light on".

Comment: @barlop, I appreciate your feedback.  While both you and Ramhound have quite a bit more Super User tenure than I do, it doesn't take too long to determine our standard "best practices." Typically, we politely ask the question's OP to edit and include any newly discovered factors into the original question.  Needless to say, that could potentially lead to a relatively obvious answer... but no, not quite quite as obvious as *""there is a power cut why is the light off."*  That is an exaggeration, at best.

Comment: @Run5k  For me it was that obvious. As soon as I discovered that re msconfig, the answer was that obvious to me.

Comment: Possibly so... but please remember that in the big scheme of things we are focused on the greater good of the community, not just the OP.  While it may have been *"that obvious"* to you, I'm sure it's safe to say that you know much more about Windows than the average person on Super User.  Many people probably wouldn't know that and as I said before, typically we politely ask the question's OP to edit and include any newly discovered factors into the original question.  From what I am hearing, it sounds like @Ramhound agrees with me in that regard.

Comment: @Run5k this is Superuser, note the super. If an option says "selective startup" and there is an issue that certain services aren't starting up and there is an adjacent option saying normal startup, then it should be that obvious.

Comment: @Run5k It's a lot like if USB isn't working and the guy finds out that USB is disabled in the BIOS.  Do you think he should add that into his question "USB is disabled in the BIOS, and USB isn't working. What can I do to make USB work?"    Playing dumb doesn't help anybody. There is no harm in the statement about checking that setting being in the answer and it even makes more sense there than from the questioner.

Comment: @Run5k Also if somebody had commented and said "Check msconfig"  or Check msconfig, is it in selective startup or normal startup.. make sure it's on normal startup.   I wouldn't then add that to the question. I'd say  "that worked, post that as the answer". I suppose I could put that in my answer to really spell it out rather than stating the discovery.  I have just updated my answer

Comment: Now that I have finally had the chance to read the extended chat discussions, it is rather obvious that this question had quickly evolved into a contentious topic long before I arrived.  I am always glad to help, but if I had known that there was already a heated debate occurring behind the scenes I would never have posted my initial comment.  One way or another, I am glad to see that the problem was solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72271/discussion-between-barlop-and-run5k).